# How can I sign the executable file and verify its integrity, using ELF executable file and RSA?

Tags: c, rsa, elf, signature, integrity

I am studying about ELF file and code integrity, trying to make a related C code that works on Linux, uses gcc for command "make". With this code, I tried to achieve two features:
First, signing executable sections. With the executable file(which is made by my code and Makefile) `signtool` and the RSA private key(produced by `$ openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048`), I am trying to sign the executable file with using the command `$ ./signtool sign -e <path to executable file> -k <path to private_key.pem>`. During the procedure, I am going to put the signature in a new section called `.signature`.
Second, verifying code integrity. With the signed executable file from previous feature and the RSA public key(produced by `$ openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem -pubout`), I am trying to perform code integrity check(verifying the signature) using the command `$ ./signtool verify -e <path to signed executable file> -k <path to public_key.pem>`. If the check succeeds, `OK` will be printed; `NOT_OK` if the check fails, and `NOT_SIGNED` if the given executable has not been signed.

With these goals, I wrote a C code and a Makefile, but even though I give the executable,a properly signed ELF executable file to verify, **it prints "NOT_OK"**

Below is my C code, for the features that I've explained:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libelf.h>
#include <gelf.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <elf.h>

#define MAX_SECTION_NAME_SIZE 256

char* readSection(char* fileName, char* sectionName) {
    int fd;
    char *name, *buffer = NULL;
    struct stat st;
    uint8_t *mem;
    Elf *e;
    Elf64_Ehdr *ehdr = NULL;
    Elf64_Shdr *shdr = NULL;
    fd = open(fileName, O_RDONLY);
    e = elf_begin(fd, ELF_C_READ, NULL);
    fstat(fd, &st);
    mem = mmap(NULL, st.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    ehdr = (Elf64_Ehdr *)mem;
    shdr = (Elf64_Shdr *)&mem[ehdr->e_shoff];

    int shnum = ehdr->e_shnum;
    Elf64_Shdr *sh_strtab = &shdr[ehdr->e_shstrndx];
    const char *const sh_strtab_p = mem + sh_strtab->sh_offset;
    for (int i = 0; i < shnum; ++i) {
        if (!strcmp(sh_strtab_p + shdr[i].sh_name, sectionName)) {
            buffer = malloc(shdr[i].sh_size);
            if (!buffer) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            memcpy(buffer, &mem[shdr[i].sh_offset], shdr[i].sh_size);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!buffer) {
        if (!strcmp(sectionName, ".signature")) {
            printf("NOT_SIGNED\n");
            exit(0);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Section not found: %s\n", sectionName);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    close(fd);
    return buffer;
}

int add_section(char *infilepath, unsigned char *buf, size_t buf_len) {
    int ret = 0;
    char *outfilepath = NULL;
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if (access(infilepath, F_OK) != 0) {
        ret = -4;
        goto clean;
    }

    if (buf == NULL) {
        ret = -2;
        goto clean;
    }

    if (buf_len == 0) {
        ret = -3;
        goto clean;
    }

    char *ext = "-signed";
    outfilepath = malloc(strlen(infilepath) + strlen(ext) + 1);
    if (outfilepath == NULL) {
        ret = -1;
        goto clean;
    }
    strcpy(outfilepath, infilepath);
    strcat(outfilepath, ext);

    fp = fopen("/tmp/signtool-sig", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        ret = -5;
        goto clean;
    }
    if (fwrite(buf, buf_len, 1, fp) != 1) {
        ret = -6;
        goto clean;
    }
    fflush(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = NULL;

    ret = execlp("objcopy", "objcopy", "--add-section", ".signature=/tmp/signtool-sig", "--set-section-flags", ".signature=noload,readonly", infilepath, outfilepath, (char *)NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        goto clean;
    }

clean:
    if (outfilepath) {
        free(outfilepath);
    }
    if (fp) {
        fclose(fp);
    }
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %d\n", ret);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int iin, ikey;
    for(int i=2; i < 5;i+=2){
        if(!strcmp(argv[i], "-e")) iin = i+1;
        else if(!strcmp(argv[i], "-k")) ikey = i+1;
    }
    FILE* pemkey = fopen(argv[ikey], "r");
    if(!strcmp(argv[1], "sign")){
        char* in = readSection(argv[iin], ".text");
        RSA *rsa = RSA_new();
        PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(pemkey, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
        char encrypt[RSA_size(rsa)*2];
        int integrity = RSA_private_encrypt(strlen(in), in, encrypt, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
        add_section(argv[iin], encrypt, RSA_size(rsa));
    }else{
        char* in = readSection(argv[iin], ".signature");
        RSA *rsa = RSA_new();
        PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(pemkey, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
        char decrypt[RSA_size(rsa)];
        int integrity = RSA_public_decrypt(RSA_size(rsa), in, decrypt, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
        char* text = readSection(argv[iin], ".text");
        printf("%d", integrity);
        printf("%s", text);
        if(integrity != -1){
            if(!strncmp(decrypt, text, strlen(text))){
                printf("OK\n");
            }else{
                printf("NOT_OK\n");
            }
        }
        else{
            printf("NOT_OK\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And below is the Makefile that I've used for the make command:

```
signtool: signtool.o
    gcc -o $@ signtool.o -lelf -lcrypto

signtool.o: signtool.c
```

With the C code, Makefile, appropriate private & public RSA key generated by the method I've introduced earlier, and a ELF executable file, I expected the result like this:
For the signing, a signed ELF executable file will be given to me. and as for the verifying, with the right signed ELF executable file, "OK" will be printed.
But as I proceeded with my code, although the signing looks like it works well, the verifying does not work as I think: **It prints "NOT_OK" regardless of the integrity of the given file**. What should I do?? **PLEASE HELP...**

Comment: `strlen(in)`?  Strings?  For binary data?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks for the comment! You mean, "int integrity = RSA_private_encrypt(strlen(in), in, encrypt, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);" part at main function? I used strlen(in) in the RSA_private_encrypt() function, to represent the size of the data that will be encrypted... Is my approach wrong?

Comment: binary files, like executables, are going to have some '\0' characters, so strlen will only give you the length to the first zero byte. You can use a byte array for the data but you can't use string functions like that.

Comment: @Misteltein Yes, your approach is wrong. `strlen` will try and find C strings that terminate using `0x00` byte. Files may contain any data, including one or more `0x00` characters. Now if you are encrypting a textual file then your approach may work, but generally you will sign too little data (`0x00` is very common in executables). During verification you have got randomized bytes to work with. Obviously `strlen` is entirely insufficient here, there are other ways to obtain the size of the file.

Comment: You should use signature generation algorithms / OpenSSL EVP functions, not the low level `RSA_` functions.

Comment: @ChaseLP Thanks for the commant! I must find another way to represent the length of the executable file...Then, what about the decryption part?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks for the comment! Other ways to obtain the size of the file...Then, what about the decryption part? Isn't there anything wrong at that part?

Comment: Fix the other errors first, using raw RSA decrypt without performing any padding or hashing is wrong entirely. Raw RSA "encrypt" with a private key is not secure, and you cannot sign large parts of plaintext with it. Usually you'd *stream* files or sections of files, not read them into memory entirely.

Comment: You are getting a byte count for when you read sections, pass the address of an int to the read function and store the size in there, then you can use that instead of strlen.